# ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libtheoraenc.so.1

Tags: libraries, ffmpeg

When I want to run ffmpeg I get the following error:

`ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libtheoraenc.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

This is output of `ls \usr\lib -l | grep libtheora`:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    419238 Jan  5  2010 libtheora.a
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root       935 Jan  5  2010 libtheora.la
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root        19 Jan  5  2010 libtheora.so -> libtheora.so.0.3.10
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    145636 Jan  5  2010 libtheoradec.a
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root       948 Jan  5  2010 libtheoradec.la
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root        21 Jan  5  2010 libtheoradec.so -> libtheoradec.so.1.1.4
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    334696 Jan  5  2010 libtheoraenc.a
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root       954 Jan  5  2010 libtheoraenc.la
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root        21 Jan  5  2010 libtheoraenc.so -> libtheoraenc.so.1.1.2
```

What should I do to solve the problem?

Edit: in line:

`libtheoraenc.so -> libtheoraenc.so.1.1.2`

I can't find libtheoraenc.so.1.1.2 in /usr/lib(packages libtheora and libtheora-dev are installed)

output of `locate libtheoraenc.so.1.1.2` is:

/usr/lib/libtheoraenc.so.1

/usr/lib/libtheoraenc.so.1.1.2

But I can't find this files in /usr/lib!

Comment: Did you install ffmpeg manually or using your distribution's package manager? Did you make sure that libtheora is the latest version?

Comment: I installed ffmpeg with apt-get. How do I know that libtheora is the latest version? If it's not, How can I install the latest

Comment: Run `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` for an upgrade of all installed packages to the current version.

Comment: Yes. It's the last version

Comment: Looks like a bug in the package then. Try reporting the bug/looking for solution on your distribution's website.

Comment: Please see edited post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'd recommend a reinstall of libtheora0:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libtheora0
```

And since you have some non-unixey backslashes in your original question, let's be explicit about looking for the libraries:

```
ls -l /usr/lib/libtheoraenc*
```