# /root/bin/ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libtheoraenc.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: centos, ffmpeg

My `ffmpeg` command gives error when I try to convert video format.
I have installed `ffmpeg` manually [following this guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CentosCompilationGuide).

For above issue I checked [ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libtheoraenc.so.1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34023/ffmpeg-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libtheoraenc-so-1) also but not able to resolve my issue.

My command is : `/root/bin/ffmpeg -i /home/pulsebrk/public_html/beta/user_uploads/6/1148a008470721f06c8dc71efa70622f99799e91.avi -acodec libvorbis -ac 2 -ab 96k -ar 44100 -b 345k -s x /home/pulsebrk/public_html/beta/user_uploads/6/1148a008470721f06c8dc71efa70622f99799e91.ogv`
and error is:

```
/root/bin/ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libtheoraenc.so.1: 
   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

libtheroa version is : 1.1.1

Comment: OS, please. And why didn't you use your distribution's binary package? Is none available?

Comment: I assumed you were using CentOS since you referenced the CentOS installation instructions for ffmpeg. Please confirm this and also which version of CentOS, 5 or 6?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue sounds like you don't have the correct version of the `libtheoraenc` library for this particular version of `ffmpeg`. That's what this message is complaining about:

```
/root/bin/ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libtheoraenc.so.1:
```

#### Configured + compiled library correctly?

When you built `ffmpeg` did you also include the ["Additional libraries"](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CentosCompilationGuide#AdditionalLibraries) mentioned on that page as well as include the additional configure switches when you built `ffmpeg`?

```
$ ./configure --enable-libtheora ....
```

#### Libraries in LD's cache?

If you have done all this the 2 other things to investigate would be did you update your shared library cache?

```
$ ldconfig -v
```

Also make sure if you did install `libtheoranc` manually that the directory it was installed into is present in your shared library `.conf` file, typically `/etc/ld.so.conf` or that there's a file present in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` with the path to the directory.

#### Shared libraries are accounted for?

Lastly you can see where shared libraries are coming from with the command `ldd /path/to/ffmpeg`.

#### Example

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/ls
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffefdfe000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x0000003d89600000)
    libcap.so.2 => /lib64/libcap.so.2 (0x0000003fa6200000)
    libacl.so.1 => /lib64/libacl.so.1 (0x0000003fa4e00000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003f8ba00000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003f8c200000)
    libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x0000003d89200000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003f8c600000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003f8b600000)
    libattr.so.1 => /lib64/libattr.so.1 (0x0000003fa3600000)
```

Make sure that each dynamic library name (on the left) is pointing to a corresponding file on disk (on the right).

Comment: I recompiled ffmpeg thrice and added ffmpeg lib path to ld.so.conf.d. and it resolved this issue.
Now I'm able to convert video from avi to ogv, if I directly fire command from putty on server, but same command is not working from PHP webpage.

Comment: I tried giving permission to ffmpeg installation directory as well bin directory but no any luck.

Comment: @Paks - so wait this solves your original issue, right? You probably should make that a new Q, it's likely something completely unrelated to building ffmpeg, and please remember to mark this as the accepted A so other's know your issue's been resolved w/ building ffmpeg.

Answer (score -1):

You need add the `libtheoraenc.so.1` file to `/usr/lib` or `/usr/lib64`.

Comment: Welcome to Unix.SE! Please explain how to go about adding this file, that would make the answer useful...